# Can I ask a question about a very complex server-side-client-side issue, but I can't provide a full MCVE?

Tags: discussion, questions, minimal-reproducible-example

I've a problem with a huge amount of server-side and client-side code involved. I can narrow down the code to a sensible count of lines to introduce the problem well enough, but with the narrowed-down code, the issue can't be reproduced by recreating the example code to the corresponding environments.

These types of "multi-environment" questions need a real good explanations of the problem at hands, of course, because a reproducible example would often require accurate knowledge of the settings of the server etc.

My question is, can we ask a question with a large code narrowed so down, that the issue is not reproducible with the provided code, but when "virtually executed", can lead to an answer.

(I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I faced a [bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392471/changing-the-title-during-asking-the-question-messes-the-similar-questions-lis) when asking this question.)

Comment: You described a scenario where it is likely you'll eventually have to post the answer yourself.  That is not a problem.

Comment: Well, I got my problem solved while trying to create a reproducible example for the question. "This one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers". In a way, SO answers the question even when it was never asked = ).

Comment: Yup, the [rubber ducky](https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/) did it again.

Comment: In principle not. Debugging questions require an mcve, because if the problem is not reproducible, most users will not be able to solve it efficiently. But I guess there is no rule without exception and these hard to catch bugs are really bugging.

Comment: Probably instead you could post a question about "how to debug X" and answer with your thought process. Like, how to debug error 16?

Comment: While I think @Braiam suggestion is pretty much the only way to ask such question I'm afraid it's still dangerously too close to "too broad" (as asking for a list). It's probably worth a try to ask anyway... Also check if https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ is better place for asking that way - it feels it could be, but I don't know.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've solved my own problem when typing it up as an SO question. Often it's not really rubber-ducking, it's that rephrasing the question in a way that others can more easily understand it makes ME able to understand where I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: No.

---

Long answer: We only know what you tell us about a problem. We don't, for instance, know what other things are in your environment that could be contributing to the problem unless you tell us. We don't really know which of them are important either, so unless you know, we're in the dark.

Why does this matter? Well, if you don't show us code that creates your problem, how can we be sure we're actually seeing your problem? Sure, you might explain your problem very well, but without seeing actual code that reproduces the problem we just can't really be sure that we are seeing the same problem. Thus, we can't give you a satisfactory answer either.

If the code you post doesn't have a problem, then we are reduced to guessing both your problem and its answer based on what we think *might* be causing the problem. This is particularly difficult if you do have a complex environment. There are so many variables here that we simply have no way of knowing. And if we're wrong, it will leave both you and us frustrated. That's no fun.

It's not that we don't want to help you. It's just that without a reproducible example, we *can't* help you--not in the way you need to be helped. Or at the very least, it's difficult to help you effectively. Not to mention that future readers might find it confusing if we give an answer that fixes a problem that is not shown in your question.

So no. That's why we don't allow questions without reproducible examples on SO. It sets everyone up for failure, and reduces your chances of getting the help you need.

Comment: That is when [psychic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208206/closed-questions-pay-attention-to-those-who-are-answering/208208#208208) [debugging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/policy-and-rationale-for-making-close-votes-invisible-to-most-users/186047#186047) comes to the rescue.