# Changing the title during asking the question messes the "Similar questions" list

Tags: bug, design, user-experience, similar-questions

When asking a question on MSO, and after writing some text to the title, and then changing the title, the list of "Similar questions" seems to act weirdly.

When the I wrote the original title, the list was populated with some proposals related to the title. But when I later changed the title, new proposals on the list were placed over the old-ones, and the old proposals were not removed. Like so:

[image]

I'd assume this is not the expected behavior when viewing the list...? The bug occurred on Windows 10 and Firefox 71.0, I haven't tested on other browsers.

Comment: Ironically this was closed as a dup, because Similar questions was unreadable = ).